# How to write a Java method which will run when server startup?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to load some information from database, and share it in Application Scope

But I don't know where to write this method, can I initialize data in Application Scope when I start the server?

Comment: Does this help: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), whose `contextInitialized()` method is called when the webapp is initialized by the container, and which has access to the servlet context (i.e. the application scope)

Answer (score -1):

You can go for `load-on-startup`  tells the servlet container to load the specified resource at server startup

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>yourServletName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>yourServletClass</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: why negative vote without any reason?

Comment: sorry but where i did tell "the server not to load on startup."

Comment: @chrylis the number is for the loading priority order, not a boolean value.

Comment: My apologies, I've only ever seen it specified as "1", and I've moved away from `web.xml`. Still not the downvoter. ;-)